# Neo4j - RESTful API POST method

Tags: php, rest, laravel-5, neo4j, neoeloquent

I'm using `Neo4j` with `PHP`.
I'm using `Laravel framework` and an `OGM` called `NeoEloquent`.
When performing a create method to create a node, this `OGM` sends a post request as described in the documentation [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/#rest-api-create-node-with-properties).
Is there any way to log this action as a `Cypher` create query.

Comment: I am sure you have already searched it but if not, please check - https://github.com/Vinelab/NeoEloquent

Answer (score 0):

Just a note to whoever lands on this question, the author provided more details in this question: [Laravel - Neoeloquent query log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47868678/laravel-neoeloquent-query-log)

And is currently working on the fix for the mentioned issue.

Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/5460250/ali-wassouf